# Why does converting a std::smatch to C-string give empty result?

Tags: c++

I have a `std::smatch` which I need convert to a `const char*` C-string.  Calling `str().c_str()` on the `smatch` gives an empty result.  However, just calling `str()` gives the expected result.  I can then call `c_str()` on that result to get the C-string.

Could there be a temporary object at fault?  If so, I can't spot it.

```
std::string input{ "1234" };
std::regex r{ "[\\d]*" };
std::smatch sm;
std::regex_match(input, sm, r);

auto s1 = sm[0].str(); // 1234
auto s2 = s1.c_str(); // 1234
auto s3 = sm[0].str().c_str(); // why empty?

std::cout << "s1: " << s1 << std::endl;
std::cout << "s2: " << s2 << std::endl;
std::cout << "s3: " << s3 << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
s1: 1234
s2: 1234
s3:
```

I need the C-string because it's required by `strtol()`, which I use later.

gcc appears to give a result for `s3`, but MSVC has an empty `s3`.

Comment: Don't use `strtol`.   Use `std::stol` instead which takes a `std::string`

Comment: I use `strtol` because it doesn't throw.  My input can be either  a long or a string.  I don't show that code, because I'm really asking about something else, but I didn't want to rely on exceptions for program logic.